# Java Kafka Client Dynamic Sasl Jaas config update

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is there way to dynamically update Java client Kafka producers  sasl jaas config without stopping/recreating client each time of Jaas config update?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Jaas config has a template that looks like `org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="%s" password="%s";` , which is used for authentication. If, for example, Kafka cluster administrator change password of the user it won't be disconnected automatically, after some time you'll get an error and session will be terminated. You can something like

```
try{
      final Consumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
      consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));
} catch (KafkaException ke){
    // here comes code that restarts consumer
}
```

But, whenever the use-case, changing this configuration would require client re-authorization, that would disrupt consumption/producing of records.

Comment: Ya so whenever this password change happens do we have to create a new client(consumer or producer)? Just want to know if we have other way to do cleint re-authorization.

Comment: yes, you have to create (or re-create) the client. This is the way ;)